# Express.js ER_PARSE_ERROR when insert values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want insert values in my database but i get a error "er_parse_error". I don't know where is the problem.
The code

```
var data = {};
function register(req,res,data) {
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({"code": 100, "status": "Error"});
        return;
    }
    var sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ?";
    connection.query(sql, data, function (err, rows) {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(rows);
        } else {
            res.json(err.code);
        }
    })
});

router.route('/client/register')

.post(function(req,res) {
    data = {
        "usuer": req.query.user,
        "password": req.query.password,
    };
    register(req, res, datos);
});
```

Comment: register(req, res, datos); ? is that a typo when pasting the code here? wich middleware are you using? mssql?

Comment: yes, is a error typo, i forgot translate to english...

Comment: So, I use mssql it's very simple and straight forward, i don't know how your middleware parses the data into the ? holder..

Comment: Ok, i solved the problem. I change "values" for "set" in the insert query.